# Depend on gradle project using ivy

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, gradle, ivy

I'm working on a web app, using JPA, Hibernate and Ivy for dependency management.

Adding the dependency to hibernate from the maven repo is straightforward, but now i need to modify hibernate source, rebuild it and add my own fork as dependency.

The problem is that hibernate use gradle. I managed to build it (gradlew clean build), and now i have all the jars in each hibernate sub project (hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-core, etc ).

My project right now depend on other projects in my workspace, but these use ivy, and thus i can add them as dependency with no trouble (using resolve in workspace feature). Now i can't figure out how to import hibernate...

(I'm not even sure how to manage an hibernate fork... in another project i've forked i've simply configured ivy (also the forked project use ivy) to use a branch, this way i'm sure to resolve to my fork and not the original project, but hibernate use gradle...so i can't use a branch)

*aProject/ivy.xml*

```
<info
    organisation="it.example"
    module="aProject"
    branch="myFork"
    status="integration">
</info>
```

*myProject/ivy.xml*

```
<dependency org="it.example" name="aProject" branch="myFork" rev="latest.integration" conf="runtime->default"/>
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution? (or point me the right way ?)

Comment: Can't you add you hibernate fork to your maven repo and get it from there? Than it should behave like any other dependency, but I'm no ivy expert and also never forked hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the Casey advice (thank you Casey) and modify the gradle script to publish to my repo. (in the local repo since i get an error trying to publish on the local network one, but this is another problem)

Here's what i've done:
in build.gradle:

```
    uploadArchives {
        repositories.mavenDeployer {
            name = 'localDeployer'
            configuration = configurations.deployerJars
            pom.project pomConfig
            repository(url: "file://C:/Users/<myUserName>/.m2/local/")
        }
    }
```

*(i was not able to use a property like ${user.home}, if someone know how to do should gently edit this)*

in ivysettings.xml

```
<resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local-maven-2" m2compatible="true"
        local="true">
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.m2/local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].[ext]" />
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.m2/local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].pom" />
    </filesystem>
</resolvers>
```

The rest is straightforward, you just need to edit the hibernate (or your forked library) version to state it as a custom one (eg. 4.2.3 -> 4.2.3-lelmarir) and use this in ivy dependency